# Queue has multiple actors in it, how does one process it?

Tags: message-queue, amazon-sqs

I apologise for the super basic question, I'm still trying to learn how to work with message queues.

The case:

Each user has a "worker" that can only process one task at a time for that user. If a queue looks like this:

```
[
    { taskForUser: 4, data { ...payload } },
    { taskForUser: 3, data { ...payload } },
    { taskForUser: 4, data { ...payload } },
    { taskForUser: 1, data { ...payload } },
    { taskForUser: 2, data { ...payload } },
    { taskForUser: 2, data { ...payload } },
    { taskForUser: 1, data { ...payload } },
    { taskForUser: 1, data { ...payload } } 
]
```

I'd like to ensure that each user's worker is occupied with no one sitting idle, and as soon as a job for that user is completed, I'd like that user to take the next job for themselves.

Essentially, this feels like multiple queues - a queue for each user.

For simplicity, seems like dynamically creating a queue for each new user sign up seems like a decent solution. However that would have issues like polling SQS too much.

Perhaps I fundamentally misunderstand how SQS works, but how best do I solve this?

Comment: Specifying that each user of a site/app would have a dedicated worker seems like the place where you have a flaw in your design... but it's actually somewhat unclear what a "user" means here, since things would get pretty out of hand pretty quickly for each user to have a dedicated *anything* at scale.  More insight into the nature of what you are building and what a "user" is and what it means when *users* (workers?) are "taking" jobs and how users and specific jobs are related may be in order.   SQS *might* have a role here, or not, but the question isn't clear enough yet, I suspect.

Comment: Can you please clarify the requirement and question? Creating and deleting queues programmatically is a very common thing to do.